# Why does datetime->days always returns a positive number

Tags: php, datetime

```
// Difference from a date in the future:
$a = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
$b = new DateTime('2000-01-05');
$interval = $b->diff($a);
return $interval->days;             // Returns 4


// Difference from a date in the past:
$a = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
$b = new DateTime('1999-12-28');
$interval = $a->diff($b);           // Arguments swapped
return $interval->days;             // Returns 4
```

Why do both of these functions return positive 4?
How do I return a negative number if a date is in the past?

Comment: The return value of `Diff` is a `DateInterval` object. How are you outputting it?

Comment: Sorry, typo in my code, updated now

Comment: `DateInterval` objects have the `invert` property that specifies whether they're positive or negative: http://php.net/manual/de/class.dateinterval.php

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You could use [`DateInterval::format`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php).

`return $interval->format("%r%a");`

Cast to int if needed:

`return (int)$interval->format("%r%a");`

Comment: It's not clear that $objA->diff($objB) == $objB - $objA. I will add a new answer with details.

Answer (score 30):

If Date is in past then invert will 1.
If Date is in future then invert will 0.

```
$invert    = $interval->invert;
```

Comment: This answer is incomplete / confusing: `If Date is in past ...` which Date ? You compare two dates mate ;)

Comment: To answer the question ("Why does datetime->days always returns a positive number?"): If you expect a negative return value, this is represented by $interval->invert = 1

Answer (score 12):

Here is your answer:

```
$today = new DateTime();
$date = new DateTime('2013-03-10');
$interval = $today->diff($date);
echo $interval->format("%r%a");
```

[Test it here](http://ideone.com/cZofdl)

Answer (score 5):

When you are diffing two DateTime objects, the following rule applies:

```
$objA->diff($objB) == $objB - $objA
```

As an example:

```
$todayDateObj = new \DateTime('2016/5/26');
$foundedDateObj = new \DateTime('1773/7/4');

$interval = $todayDateObj->diff($foundedDateObj);
echo $interval->format('%r%a') . "\n\n";
// -88714

$interval2 = $foundedDateObj->diff($todayDateObj);
echo $interval2->format('%r%a');
// 88714
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use timestamp like this.

```
<?php 
    $date1 = '2015-01-02';
    $date2 = '2015-01-05';
    $diff = strtotime($date1, 'Y-m-d') - strtotime($date2, 'Y-m-d'); 
?>
```

$diff will return negative or positive.